# How to test SSO(or kerberos) enabled application via Jmeter? How can I know the kdc and admin_server values used for the kerberos authentication?

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to test SSO enabled application via Jmeter.But I am facing issue in configuring kerb5.config and jaas.config files in jmeter/bin folder and getting 401 error while replaying the script in Jmeter.I am not able to find the kdc and admin_server values.From where I get these values?
Can anyone suggest any solution ?
And if any other way to do the SSO authentication in Jmeter, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

No one here will tell you what values to use (unless there is a colleague of yours who is aware of domain controllers setup in your organisation or SUT infrastructure) so I can come up with only generic answer:

Looking into [Kerberos Documentation](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.12/doc/admin/conf_files/krb5_conf.html)

> **admin_server**
>
> Identifies the host where the administration server is running. Typically, this is the master Kerberos server. This tag must be given a value in order to communicate with the `kadmind` server for the realm.
>
> **kdc**
>
> The name or address of a host running a KDC for that realm. An optional port number, separated from the hostname by a colon, may be included. If the name or address contains colons (for example, if it is an IPv6 address), enclose it in square brackets to distinguish the colon from a port separator. For your computer to be able to communicate with the KDC for each realm, this tag must be given a value in each realm subsection in the configuration file, or there must be DNS SRV records specifying the KDCs.

So:

- for `kdc` use any domain controller
- for `admin_server` either use your primary domain controller or in case of [replicated Kerberos setup](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Kerberos-Infrastructure-HOWTO/server-replication.html) it should be the master server

In a very simple setup you can use IP address of your primary (or only) domain controller for both settings, you can determine it by pinging your domain name.

More information:

- [How to Manually Configure a Kerberos Client](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-4557/setup-341/index.html)
- [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/ja/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter)